# Incorrect stage orientation in Adobe AIR iOS publishing?

Tags: ios, flash, actionscript, air, landscape

I'm developing a game in Adobe Flash, using Adobe AIR to publish a version for iOS devices. The issue I'm encountering is being unable to turn the stage's orientation to Landscape - it appears permanently stuck on Portrait. The publish settings make no difference to this, even when set to Landscape, the game doesn't turn. What is strange is that the iPhone menu at the top does orient to Landscape - so the clock reads landscape, whilst the game is still in portrait. Has anybody ever encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a framework that may change dynamicaly the orientation ?

Otherwise the right way to get Landscape only in a Air application is to set the following in your nameofyourapp-app.xml

```
<autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
<aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
```